# Should underscore(_) prefix be added to method input parameters in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Both compiles but I wonder which version is correct?

```
  int add(int _a, int _b) {
    return _a + _b;
  }
```

or

```
  int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Effective Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#dont-use-a-leading-underscore-for-identifiers-that-arent-private)

> ***There is no concept of “private” for local variables, parameters, or library prefixes.*** When one of those has a name that starts with an underscore, it sends a confusing signal to the reader. To avoid that, don’t use leading underscores in those names.

So according to the guideline below code is more correct,

```
 int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
  }
```